# How to use bootstrap styling in django project

Tags: css, django, python-3.x, bootstrap-4

I have downloaded bootstrap files (`css`, `js`) and put in the `static` folder of my project and made changes in header section of `index.html` as shown in the below code. But still `django` can't locate bootstrap.min.css as shown in the error

> "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1687

**Project Structure**

```
Project
|---Project
|---static
    |---css
    |---js
|---templates
    |---index.html
|---manage.py
```

**index.html**

```
<head>
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type='text/css' />
</head>
```

I followed tutorials and read documentation But could not locate the problem can anybody help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not seeing anything wrong with your HTML or Project Structure.

Did you set [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) in your settings.py?

### settings.py

```
# Add this at the end of your code if it isn't there already

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join("Project", "static"),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your settings.py, should have BASE_DIR. It should look like this:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

And add STATICFILES_DIRS at the end of your settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```